# Is there a performance impact for capturing additional data in nginx logs?

Tags: performance, memory, logging, nginx

I have my nginx logs set to default:

```
$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
'"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
```

However, I need to change it to add upstream time and response time, so I did the following:

```
 log_format with_response_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
 '$request_time $upstream_response_time
```

However, I am not sure if this will have a performance impact on my website. I did some stress testing using apache JMeter to see if there is any different RAM usage but didn't find anything wild. I also noted that for each entry, the number of bytes added is about 20 bytes. I am not worried about the space, more about RAM usage.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance impact would in most cases be minimal. A quick scan of the [source](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/master/src/http) shows that the values of those variables are calculated internally regardless of whether they used in the logging so the only overhead is the additional time to append those values onto the log entry and write to output - usually a disk based file.

The additional time is going to be minimal compared to the overall processing overhead. This is also my own experience of logging response times just as you are suggesting.